# Changing the query data source to new updated sheet questions

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

We are utilizing an excel monthly report in our power bi project that has added measure columns, and we keep the sheets the fields pull the data from in one folder. When we get each month's updated excel sheet, would we be able delete the old one, add the new report to the folder with the exact same name as the old, and refresh the power bi query to use the new updated data? All the column headers would remain the same, the only thing that would be changing is maybe the amount of rows and the data within them. If we were to keep all the names the same, the only thing changing is the data sheet itself (not the column headers just the data) would the added measure columns remain and work? The measure columns act as column data multipliers and filters, and it would be a pain to make new ones each month.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the file path and filename and sheet/table name all remain the same, Power BI won't know the difference and you shouldn't have trouble if the columns and headers stay consistent.

Additionally, if you don't want to rename the file or delete/move older files from the folder, you could do a Load from Folder query and sort by date created/modified and grab the top row instead of specifying the filename.

Comment: Ok, and the column measures added in Power BI to the field query's will remain and work.

Comment: The calculated columns? Yes. Those should still work.